# X264 & ARM encoding on Android

Tags: android, encoding, ffmpeg, arm, x264

I recently built a Video encoding class that runs on Android using ffmpeg and native code. I am surprised by the time it takes to encode a video, about 1 frame / second at best. I have tried with x264 and settings optimised for speed and with mpeg as well - no real difference.

The x264 library now has support for ARM architecture and is meant to be quite efficient on these boasting over 20fps encoding speed. I am not sure I am using it correctly. Here the script I use for compiling:

```
./configure --prefix=$PREFIX \
--enable-shared \
--enable-static \
--disable-gpac \
--enable-debug \
--extra-cflags=" -I$ARM_INC -fPIC -DANDROID -fpic -mthumb-interwork -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fno-short-enums -D__ARM_ARCH_5__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5T__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5E__ -D__ARM_ARCH_5TE__ -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -msoft-float -mthumb -O3 -fomit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -finline-limit=64 -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -MMD -MP " \
--extra-ldflags=" -nostdlib -Bdynamic -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc -Wl,-soname,/usr/lib/libz.so -Wl,-rpath-link=$ARM_LIB,-dynamic-linker=/system/bin/linker -L$ARM_LIB -lc -lm -ldl -lgcc" \
--cross-prefix=${ARM_PRE}- \
--disable-asm \
--host=arm-linux \
```

I believe the last line should so what I am after ie enable ARM optimisations. Maybe I am missing something.

For info I am encoding a 640x480 video on a Nexus 7 tablet. Here are my encoder settings (x264)

```
c->gop_size       = 12;
c->pix_fmt        = PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
c->max_b_frames   = 0;
c->scenechange_threshold = 0;
c->rc_buffer_size = 0;
```

Thanks

Comment: The built in Media Recorder will be using a hardware encoder, optimized and built for the chip on the phone. What resolution video are you encoding? 1 frame/1 sec seems very slow! Also, you have to post more details about the processor capability of the device that you are testing this on.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Added those details in the original post

Comment: I am not familiar with development on Android and I am not sure how mush access you have to the internal drivers, If you can find the driver that handles recording from the camera, your best bet would be to feed the video through it. Most Video apps transcode videos on server side.

Comment: It seems that [x264 supports hardware encoding on ARM devices](http://x264dev.multimedia.cx/archives/142) but I am probably not using it correctly - the benchmarks show over 20fps encoding speed! I am looking for information on enabling this

Comment: Are you really targetting ARMv5 as your configuration suggests? Most ARM-based Android devices released in the last couple of years are ARMv7, and that's probably what you want to target (along with NEON support) for the best possible performance.

Comment: That really improved the speed by 50% - thanks. I still find it slow (2-3fps) compared to what I read should be standard

Comment: @Tishu Video encoding is very CPU intensive, particularly motion estimation. For this reason, most ARM SoCs provide hardware acceleration for some or all of the encoding process in their camera systems.

Answer (score 0):

You should enable asm and disable debug. To avoid nasty warnimgs, run

```
 make STRIP=
```